# FatalErrorException in HomeController.php line 69: Class 'app\User' not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, classnotfound

I'm new in laravel 5.1. can you help me solving this error?

[image]

This is my code

[image]

Comment: try `\App` instead of `\app`

Comment: thank you... ^^ it works!... just the capital letter... ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should refer to the `User` model like this:

```
$datas = \App\User::paginate(5);
```

Comment: Thank you!...it works...it's just the capital [A] ...thank you thank you... :)